# Converting SQL query with inner select to sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following query to find the oldest content_revision for each piece of content (content_revision.content_id):

```
select r1.id from content_revision r1
join (
  select r2.content_id as content_id, min(ts_created) as min_ts_created from content_revision r2
  group by r2.content_id
  order by min(ts_created) desc
) as inner_result
on r1.content_id = inner_result.content_id
and r1.ts_created = inner_result.min_ts_created limit 10;
```

I'm trying to convert this to sqlalchemy (without running plain sql statements), but I'm not sure how to write the "on" part of my query. Here's what I've got so far:

```
db.session.query(RevisionModel.id)
.join(
  db.session.query(RevisionModel.content_id, func.min(RevisionMode.ts_created))
    .group_by(RevisionModel.content_id)
    .order_by(func.min(RevisionModel.ts_created).desc())
)
??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `.join()` is the join condition:

```
db.session.query(RevisionModel.id) \
          .join(subquery, and_(subquery.c.content_id == RevisionModel.content_id,
                               subquery.c.min_ts_created == RevisionModel.ts_created))
```

You'll also need to make sure convert your sub-`Query` into a `select` with correctly labeled columns:

```
subquery = db.session.query(RevisionModel.content_id.label("content_id"),
                            func.min(RevisionModel.ts_created).label("min_ts_created")) \
    .group_by(RevisionModel.content_id) \
    .order_by(func.min(RevisionModel.ts_created).desc()) \
    .subquery("inner_result")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - will experiment with this and get back to you!

Comment: Hmm - I'm taking awhile to upvote because the results are _so_ close to the results of the original query, but not exactly the same. If this leads me to solving the problem, I will upvote and edit.

Comment: The problem is that there are just a few RevisionModels missing that were in the original query. I'm still looking for a pattern here, but at this point is seems kind of random.

Comment: @wheresmycookie As far as I can tell, the generated query is pretty much identical to your raw SQL: `SELECT content_revision.id AS content_revision_id FROM content_revision JOIN (SELECT content_revision.content_id AS content_id, min(content_revision.ts_created) AS min_ts_created 
FROM content_revision GROUP BY content_revision.content_id ORDER BY min(content_revision.ts_created) DESC) AS inner_result ON inner_result.content_id = content_revision.content_id AND inner_result.min_ts_created = content_revision.ts_created`

Comment: You are right.. I made a mistake on my end. Thanks for the help!